# Why wont this run in BlueJ?

Tags: java, ide, bluej

I am trying to do the free Stanford programming course online, but the programs wont run when executed. I believe I have successfully added the acm library to BlueJ, because when I compile the code, the imports are accepted, and it doesn't show any errors. But when I try and run the program, nothing happens, and all I see is the text, "Start: applet not initialized." Please, Please, Please help.

The code I am using in BlueJ is the following:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class HelloProgram extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run() {
        add(new GLabel("hello, world", 100, 75));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the documentation for the GraphicsProgram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to install the [AMCInvoker](http://www.bluej.org/extensions/extensions.html) extension, then you create an instance of your class *HelloProgram* and call the *start* method.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Pretty straight forward, the only thing that almost tripped me up is that there is a separate menu item you click when you run these programs. It's called "Run ACM Program" after you right click on the class.